# What do the marking on these artillery shell casings in brass and steel mean?

Tags: identification, world-war-one, german, shell-casings

I have two artillery shell casings, one brass, one steel that appear identical, height 229mm/9.0" app', base diameter 91mm/3.575" app', body diameter 81mm/3.190" app, I.D. diameter 75mm/2.950" app'.

I'd like to identify them, 75mm? 77mm?
Rheinmetal manufacture?
Did Germany use steel for casings late in WWI?

I'm new here and my pictures are apparently too large to upload, so here are the markings I can read.

BRASS

St.
Jan 1917
Rh.M./198
H
75?
Sp61

STEEL ( much rust )

1918
AEG
Sp51

[image: base of a shell]

[image: base of a shell]

[image: base of a shell]

[image: base of a shell]

Comment: You can upload the photos to imgur and add a link to the album.

Comment: You can also just make the images smaller. I usually use [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) for that, which is a free (libre) image editing tool. Open the file, rectangle-select the part you want to keep, crop-to-selection, resize it down to something more reasonable, and save it to a new file name.

Comment: Thank you for the high quality photos. While we prefer inline photos, for identification questions the higher quality the better; if that means linking them so be it. And thank you for the accurate measurements.

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions indicate these are likely 77 x 230R (R for Rimmed) for 7.7cm German artillery.

### Steel shell

- AEG is the manufacturer: Algemeine Elektricität Gesellschaft Berlin (English: General Electric Company of Berlin).
- 1918 is the year of manufacture.
- SP51 is a quality control mark.

### Brass shell

"Rh.M.I." is the manufacturer's mark, and "Düsseldorf" is where it's made. I'm not aware of "Rh.M.I." in Düsseldorf, but there is an "Rh.M.F.". In the frenzy of shell production, they could have used the wrong letter. Or it could have been an asymmetrical strike and only very lightly imprinted half the letter and the rest wore off.

Compare with this almost identical mark. Note how the last digit in "191?" is almost completely worn away leaving only the left-most part. The "F" in "Rh.M.F." could have had the same fate becoming an "I".

[image]

[Some sources say "Rh.M.F." is "Rheinische Munitionsfabrik" (English: Rhenish Ammunition Factory) of Düsseldorf](https://collections.qm.qld.gov.au/objects/262478/trench-art-fashioned-from-a-discharged-german-77-cm-artillery-shell-case) which is likely referring to "Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik Aktiengesellschaft" which is [Rheinmetall](https://de-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Rheinmetall?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp).

See the discussion in the comments for more.

- Jan 1917 is when it was made.
- 198 is the lot number.
- St is for "stark" (English: "strong") indicating it has been made stronger than earlier casings.
- SP 61 is a quality control mark.

Comment: seems like it's "*Rh M I*" and not "*M F*" ? what makes it look like a F is a scratch on the brass IMO.

Comment: @OldPadawan Rh.M.I. doesn't make sense. I assume it's a mistake. I explain in the answer.

Comment: fair enough. Much better with your explanation in the answer though (imo)

Comment: @Schwern I **cannot** find a "Rheinische Munitionsfabrik"  in Düsseldorf in any publication dating to WW1 or just before the war. There was, however, the "Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik", headquartered in Düsseldorf (the precursor to today's Rheinmetall). This company operated an "Artillerie- und Infanterie-Munitionsfabrik" in Düsseldorf-Derendorf per this [advertisement](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Elektrotechnische_auskunft/kg_OAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover) from 1913.

Comment: @Schwern There was also a "Rheinische Waffen- und Munitionsfabrik G.m.b.H" in Cologne per [this publication](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Warenzeichenblatt/orbjf8IKKSwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA643&printsec=frontcover) from 1916 listing some of its trademarks, such as Solemit and Solit. Since a company with the name "Rheinische Munitionsfabrik" did not exist in the time around WW1, the shell shown must have been produced by the company in Düsseldorf that is now known as Rheinmetall.

Comment: According to https://artillerymarkings.com: "‘Rh.M.F’ which stands for the manufacturer Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik A G."

Comment: @njuffa I believe Rheinsche Metallwaaren und Maschinefabrik is RM. I'm poking around for something more definitive about Rh.M.F.

Comment: @njuffa Found a better source. [Queensland Museum Network has a shell casing](https://collections.qm.qld.gov.au/objects/262478/trench-art-fashioned-from-a-discharged-german-77-cm-artillery-shell-case) Rh.M.F. they say is from "Rheinische Munitionsfabrik" which they also identify as Rheinmetall AG.

Comment: @Schwern In my experience, secondary sources are often unreliable when it comes to historical facts. This is why I first looked for "Rheinische Munitionsfabrik" in primary sources between 1900 and 1920. Not finding any evidence of the existence of a company by that name, I then looked for other producers of artillery shells in Düsseldorf that might fit the bill besides "Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik" and came up empty-handed.

Comment: @Schwern Note that "Rheinmetall" was originally a colloquial name for "Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik". I don't know the exact date when it became (part of) the official company name. A publication by the Düsseldorf chamber of commerce dated November 16, 1918 still refers to the company as "Rheinische Metallwaaren- und Maschinenfabrik", see footnote on [p. 657](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wochenschrift/FWoaYJHSrMIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA657&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for looking at a primary source (and that font!) I need to pick up a good artillery ID book. I'm with you that the shell was likely made by Rheinmetall. Is the source listing companies or facilities? Manufactuer marks + lot number is a way to find defects in manufacture, and you'd want to trace that to a specific facility. Is it possible there were two facilities in Dusseldorf, both owned by the same company? Maybe "Rheinsche Munitionsfabrik" was a facility or dept within Rheinsche Metallwaaren und Maschinenfabrik.

Comment: Re 'Maybe "Rheinsche Munitionsfabrik" was a facility or dept within Rheinsche Metallwaaren und Maschinenfabrik.' I considered this possibility, but have yet to find any evidence of it. My working hypothesis is that some author years ago created this shorthand designation because they were unfamiliar with the details of the development of the company's name, and it propagated from there.

Comment: @njuffa [Google Books found two references](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Rheinsche+Munitionsfabrik%22&tbm=bks&hl=en&gl=us&ei=Un9vZb6CBPn80PEP84iGwAM&ved=0ahUKEwi-84eEifmCAxV5PjQIHXOEATgQsJ4FCAM). "Trench Art: An Illustrated History" associates it with Rh.M.F. The other in "Chemie-Arbeit in Werk und Labor - Volume 61". It's possible Trench Art is what people are referencing. Unfortunately the nearest copy of Trench Art is 500 miles or $400 away.

Comment: @njuffa I've summed up the naming confusion in the answer. I agree no matter the exact name, it's Rheinmetall.

Comment: @njuffa I know, I know, but typing umlauts on Windows is haaard! 